YA dystopian book involving a female about to be sterilized who eventually escapes into frames of art or an alternate world portal with other kids
I read a book published before 2004 in middle school. I'm 36, 7th grade I believe, a school set in Des Plaines, IL. Teacher gives us a book to read with assignments. Because of the assignments, is how I remember the bits of the story. I've been seeking this for a long time to reread.
I remember in the beginning-ish of the book it's describing a female about to be sterilized but that doesn't end up happening (?).
At some point, she's with a group of other kids all trying to get away and they end up consulting with some guy.
What sticks with me is the ending, because they all go into frames of art or maybe an alternate world portal where everything is beautiful and they no longer have to worry about the place they were in (?).

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Is this Portal to E'ewere (1983) by Irma Walker...?
As noted in the plot summary printed on the inside flaps of the book, the protagonist, AMitY, lives in a future where the USA has split up into a number of smaller nations. Her nation, the N'Eastern States of America, is ruled by a council of men who impose strict behavior and eugenics codes on people and assign them into overcrowded groups called swarms. However, AMitY has strange dreams of another world; a paradise called E'ewere.

In the middle of the twenty-first century, all of World/Earth had been in a state of anarchy; and in an attempt to creat some order in the area that had been the United States, many small nations evolved. The strongest of these, the tiny N'Eastern States of America, was ruled by a council of nine men, and by a rigid system of behavior mores called the Courtesy Code. Originally these were temporary measures, but two hundred years later they were unalterable law.
People live in swarms, there are so many of them. And most people die of fright at the idea of ever being alone. But AMitY is different. She has strange dreams of a world where space and aloneness are possible.
She might have achieved this in her own society, because she has attracted the attention of the son of one of the current Council of Nine. He has offered marriage. And that would mean a life in a house with amenities that AMitY can only dream about in her swarm menage. Yet she has refused ConCord Grisom because his father was responsible for the death of her parents.
ConCord, however, sees in AMitY the discontent and imagination that make her the kind of person who could help him change their world, so he makes it possible for her—without her realizing it—to find the portal into the world of which she dreams. And only there, in the paradise she sought, can she begin to see life on Earth in the proper perspective and ConCord as an individual apart from his father. And only then, after some dreadful mistakes, can she assess her own aims and her real desires.


AMitY's best friend, PRudenCe, is due to be sterilised when she turns sixteen, due to one of her ancestors being a borderline diabetic...

Since the harsh new Eugenic Code had taken effect a year ago, PRudenCe had known that when she came of age at sixteen, she would be sterilized. One of her ancestors, six generations back, had been a borderline diabetic, and although the malady hadn't manifested itself in any of her descendants since, it was enough to deprive PRudenCe of her right to bear a child, to forbid her from bonding permanently (or even from a temporary pairing) with anyone not a Sterie like herself.

... but AMitY discovers that a stained glass window in the attic above her bedroom is a portal to E'ewere and subsequently goes there with PRudenCe and some other characters.

For a long time she studied the window, admiring the tiny bits of colored glass that formed a stylized pattern of roses. As she stared, the pattern seemed to shift, reforming into something else. Was it an illusion, the artistry of the long-dead craftsman who had created the stained glass window? Or was the glass actually moving, changing?
She inhaled deeply to steady herself before she made her way to the window, stepping carefully upon the old floor boards. As if keeping time with her own racing pulses, the light intensified, ebbed, then intensified again as she drew near. Even before she reached it, the window glass, with its pattern of roses, had dissolved away completely.
Somehow, when she was close enough to touch the sill, she wasn't surprised to find out that she was staring into the place of her dreams, into the world that HUmble had called E'ewere.

The book is currently available to borrow from the Internet Archive.
